# C# How would I fill a Form1 Parameter in the same seperate class

Tags: c#, winforms

Alright. I'm making a Simon Say's game and I'm working on making a button blink. I have an extra class that has a function with parameter of Form1, in which I can access my Form1 buttons. However I don't know how to fill the parameter in that same class. You'll understand what I mean if you look at the code.

This is my seperate class code:

```
class SimonFunctions : Form1
{

    public static List<int> ColorNums = new List<int>();

    public static void ColorPlay(Form1 form, int x)
    {
        form.ButtonNum = x;
        if (x == 1)
            form.GreenButton.BackColor = Color.Lime;
        else if (x == 2)
            form.RedButton.BackColor = Color.Red;
        else if (x == 3)
            form.YellowButton.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
        else if (x == 4)
            form.BlueButton.BackColor = Color.Blue;
        form.timer1.Start();
    }

    public static void Colorplaff()
    {
        ColorPlay(HOW AM I GOING TO SPECIFY THIS, 1);
    }

}
```

This is my Form1 Code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public int ButtonNum = 0;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void StartButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SimonFunctions.Colorplaff();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ButtonNum == 1)
        {
            GreenButton.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 113, 215, 128);
            timer1.Stop();
        }
        else if (ButtonNum == 2)
        {
            RedButton.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 234, 83, 87);
            timer1.Stop();
        }
        else if (ButtonNum == 3)
        {
            YellowButton.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 128);
            timer1.Stop();
        }
        else if (ButtonNum == 4)
        {
            BlueButton.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 125, 150, 206);
            timer1.Stop();
        }
    }

    private void GreenButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GreenButton.BackColor = Color.Lime;
        ButtonNum = 1;
        timer1.Start();
    }

    private void RedButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RedButton.BackColor = Color.Red;
        ButtonNum = 2;
        timer1.Start();
    }

    private void YellowButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        YellowButton.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
        ButtonNum = 3;
        timer1.Start();
    }

    private void BlueButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BlueButton.BackColor = Color.Blue;
        ButtonNum = 4;
        timer1.Start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just change the method to be non-static (i.e. remove `static`) and then type `this`. Of course, that works only because you have declared the helper class in a very weird way: it inherits the `Form1` class for some reason. Frankly, a good "helper" class should not be dependent on a specific type of class it helps; if you're going to do that, you might as well just put all the functionality in the original class anyway and save yourself the trouble.

Comment: Alternatively, if you want to leave the two classes tightly coupled like that but still separate classes, then you have to make `Form1` pass the `this` reference to the helper methods class (which won't inherit `Form1` at all), so that it can then pass the value to other methods as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the more correct way to do it

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    SimonFunctions sf = new SimonFunctions(this); //Added

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void StartButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sf.Colorplaff(); //call Colorplaff from Form1;
    }
}

class SimonFunctions 
{
    public static List<int> ColorNums = new List<int>();
    Form1 mainForm; //added

    public SimonFunctions (Form1 form) //Constructor added
    {
        mainForm = form;
    }

    public void ColorPlay(int x) //remove static and Form1 argument
    {
        mainForm.ButtonNum = x; //use mainForm
        if (x == 1)
            mainForm.GreenButton.BackColor = Color.Lime;
        else if (x == 2)
            mainForm.RedButton.BackColor = Color.Red;
        else if (x == 3)
            mainForm.YellowButton.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
        else if (x == 4)
            mainForm.BlueButton.BackColor = Color.Blue;
        mainForm.timer1.Start();
    }

    public void Colorplaff()
    {
        ColorPlay(1);
    }
}
```